# Unit testing using mockito

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to write unit test case for bestElement() method using mockito. ClassA and ClassB are in same package. I want to test when the array list is empty and when the array list is not empty. I am new in unit testing. Please guide me how to write unit test for this method for both the cases. Also mention if any other information is required. THANKS!

```
public class ClassA{

    private final ArrayList<ClassB> array = new ArrayList<>();

    public ClassB bestElement() {

    if (array.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }

    ClassB first = array.get(0);
    array.remove(0);
    return first;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a method to add new elements to ClassB list. You can use a getter like getArray().

```
@Test
public void testBestIsFirstElement() {
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    ClassB best = new ClassB();
    ClassB b1 = new ClassB();
    a.getArray().add(best);
    a.getArray().add(b1);

    assertThat(a.bestElement(), equalTo(best));
}

@Test
public void testBestIsNullIfListIsEmpty() {
    ClassA a = new ClassA();

    assertThat(a.bestElement(), equalTo(null));
}
```

Comment: Celik.. I tried this but I am getting null error as the bestElement method is still returning null only! this getArray() method is also not working. I just created a new arrayList in test file and then just added elements in it.      private <ClassB> temp = new ArrayList<>(). and then in method bestElement() I used temp.add(best) and temp.add(b1).

Comment: Celik.. I tried this but I am getting null error as the bestElement method is still returning null only! this getArray() method is also not working. I just created a new arrayList in test file and then just added elements in it:      private <ClassB> temp = new ArrayList<>();  temp.add(best);  temp.add(b1);

Comment: getArray() should be a public method of ClassA.
Like following;
public List<ClassB> getArray() { return array; }

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use mockito in this case. Mocking is primarily used in unit testing. An object under test may have dependencies on other (complex) objects. To isolate the behavior of the object you want to test you replace the other objects by mocks that simulate the behavior of the real objects. This is useful if the the real objects are impractical to incorporate into the unit test.

I recommend to make a unit test tutorial first, check this one: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html